# Generating diagrams (in PNG or JPG) from console?

Tags: scripting, graph

From these data I can create a diagram in OpenOffice:

```
$ cat time.log 
2014-04-29 08:15:34 1.00
2014-04-29 08:15:36 1.00
2014-04-29 08:15:42 1.50
2014-04-29 08:15:47 2.00
2014-04-29 08:15:55 2.00
2014-04-29 08:16:02 3.00
2014-04-29 08:16:10 4.00
2014-04-29 08:19:31 6.00
$
```

[image]

**Q:** But how can we create the same diagram with a console program? Are there any diagram generator applications on Linux (using Ubuntu 12.04)? A "time.txt" can have an average 200 lines.

p.s.: these are outputs from command execution:

```
$ { /usr/bin/time -f "%e" sleep 6 ; } 2>&1 | sed "s/^/`date "+%F %H:%M:%S"`\t/g" >> time.log
```

Comment: GNUplot: http://www.gnuplot.info/

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed to out, [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is the right tool for the job. Below is shell script for collecting the data and generating a histogram from the data with Gnuplot:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILE=./time.log
OUTFILE=./time-plot.png

{ /usr/bin/time -f "%e" sleep 6 ; } 2>&1 | sed "s/^/`date "+%F %H:%M:%S"`\t/g" >> "$LOGFILE"

gnuplot << EOF
set lmargin at screen 0.20
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.30
set tmargin at screen 0.85
set datafile separator " "
set title ""
set ylabel ""
set yrange [0:7]
set xlabel ""
set xtics rotate by 45 right
set style fill solid 1.00 noborder
set boxwidth 2 relative
set terminal png
set output "$OUTFILE"
plot "$LOGFILE" using 3:xticlabels(stringcolumn(1) . " " . stringcolumn(2)) with histogram notitle linecolor rgb 'blue'
EOF
```

An example plot generated for the sample data provided below:

[image: Example plot generated from sample input]

Note that this example uses the tic alignment options introduced in Gnuplot 4.6.0 to match the x-axis label rotation in the sample diagram. The `right`, `left` and `center` tic alignment options are not available in the Gnuplot 4.4.3 packaged for Ubuntu 12.04. If the precise appearance is not an issue, replace `set xtics rotate by 45 right` with for instance `set xtics rotate` to make the script compatible with the older version of Gnuplot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use latex for this purpose. Just make yourself an appropriate template and afterwards cut them together. A quick and dirty example assuming your time.log looks a bit more parser friendly:

```
2014-04-29 08:15:34, 1.00
2014-04-29 08:15:36, 1.00
2014-04-29 08:15:42, 1.50
2014-04-29 08:15:47, 2.00
2014-04-29 08:15:55, 2.00
2014-04-29 08:16:02, 3.00
2014-04-29 08:16:10, 4.00
2014-04-29 08:19:31, 6.00
```

The simple template call it templ.tex (this has to be optimized to fit to your data):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bardiag}
\begin{document}

\bardiagrambegin{9.5}{20}{20cm}{1}{2}{1cm}{0.5cm}
```

And a small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="
"
cat templ.tex > new.tex
for line in `cat time.log`;do
    echo ${line} | sed -e 's/\(.*\),\s*\(.*\)/\\baritem\{\1\}\{\2\}{blue}/' >> new.tex
done
printf "\\\bardiagramend{}{}\n\\\end{document}" >> new.tex    
latex new.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago I have similar case. I use gnuplot.

You can use the following example (not tested)

diagram.p

```
set datafile separator " "
set title "Title"
set xlabel "Data"
set xtics rotate
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s"
set ylabel "Count"
set terminal png
set output "diagram.png"
plot ["2014-04-29 08:00":"2014-04-29 09:00"] 'time.log ' using 1:2 title "Diagram" with lines

gnuplot -e "load 'diagram.p'"
```

Comment: This does not appear to work (tested with Gnuplot 4.4.3 and 4.6) even after fixing the single quotes around the input file name. Besides, the OP asks for a histogram, not a line diagram.